# web.xml parsing error while starting liferay 6.2 with jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss

I am trying to migrating from web application (jboss 4.2) to jboss 7.1 with liferay 6.2
I have done some basic configuration .But now I am getting parsing error for web.xml which present in my war. How should I resolve this error in order to update web.xml

error-------
06:05:16,377 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SupplierPortal.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc
.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SupplierPortal.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "SupplierPortal.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/E:/NetUploadedLiferay/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga
3/jboss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/SupplierPortal.war/WEB-INF/web.xml" at [4,2]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more

Please help me...?

Comment: I got solution,There were <tag-lib> without <jsf-config>tags in web.xml.(But still there was not a problem in liferay 5.2)